# Trying to show dates of MIN and MAX values of each customers on DB BROWSER for SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
+----------------------------------+
| CUST_NO,YEAR_MONTH,TOTAL_DEPOSIT |
+----------------------------------+
| 1,201912,802452                  |
| 1,201911,30                      |
| 1,201910,370071                  |
| 2,201912,33                      |
| 2,201911,0                       |
| 2,201910,89                      |
| 3,201912,2                       |
| 3,201911,926091                  |
| 3,201910,82                      |
+----------------------------------+
```

On this data table I'm trying to query dates of MIN and MAX values on SQLite

Output should look like this

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║ CUST_NO,DATE_OF_MIN,DATE_OF_MAX ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1,201911,201912                 ║
║ 2,201911,201910                 ║
║ 3,201912,201911                 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝
```

This is what I have done so far;

```
SELECT 
CUST_NO
,YEAR_MONTH
,MAX(TOTAL DEPOSIT) AS TOTAL_DEP_MAX
FROM XSELL_DATAMART 
GROUP BY CUST_NO
```

so I can get the date of max but somehow I need to save this date as DATE_OF_MAX and repeat this for MIN and inner select them or create two separate tables and combine them? This is where I got stuck.

Comment: What are those: TIME_DEP and DEMAND_DEPOSIT, and what if there are moer than 1 date which has the same max or min deposit?

Comment: Oh pardon me, Total_Deposit is actually a column that I create by simply summing two different deposit types, I copy-pasted my code and forgot to edit my code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is with [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-first_value/) window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CUST_NO,
  FIRST_VALUE(YEAR_MONTH) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NO ORDER BY TOTAL_DEPOSIT) DATE_OF_MIN,
  FIRST_VALUE(YEAR_MONTH) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NO ORDER BY TOTAL_DEPOSIT DESC) DATE_OF_MAX
FROM XSELL_DATAMART
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/inr14ccd9X1R4GrvViHr2e/0).
Results:

```
| CUST_NO | DATE_OF_MIN | DATE_OF_MAX |
| ------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1       | 201911      | 201912      |
| 2       | 201911      | 201910      |
| 3       | 201912      | 201911      |
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that sure, but will give it a shot.

```
Select mn.CUST_NO, YEAR_MONTH_MIN, YEAR_MONTH_MAX
From
(
SELECT 
    d.CUST_NO
    ,d.YEAR_MONTH as YEAR_MONTH_MIN
From XSELL_DATAMART d
Inner join
(
    SELECT 
         CUST_NO
        ,MIN(TOTAL_DEPOSIT) AS TOTAL_DEP_MIN
    FROM XSELL_DATAMART 
    GROUP BY CUST_NO
    ) n on d.CUST_NO = n.CUST_NO and d.TOTAL_DEPOSIT = n.TOTAL_DEP_MIN
) mn
Inner join 
(
SELECT 
    d.CUST_NO
    ,d.YEAR_MONTH as YEAR_MONTH_MAX
From XSELL_DATAMART d
Inner join
(
    SELECT 
         CUST_NO
        ,MAX(TOTAL_DEPOSIT) AS TOTAL_DEP_MAX
    FROM XSELL_DATAMART 
    GROUP BY CUST_NO
    ) n on d.CUST_NO = n.CUST_NO and d.TOTAL_DEPOSIT = n.TOTAL_DEP_MAX
)mx on mn.CUST_NO = mx.CUST_NO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFrJeNEabQ1s51oZMfR5RQ/5).

```
 select
      CUST_NO,
      min(YEAR_MONTH) as DATE_OF_MAX,
      max(YEAR_MONTH) as DATE_OF_MIN
  from
  (
    select
      CUST_NO,
      YEAR_MONTH,
      row_number() over (partition by CUST_NO order by TOTAL_DEPOSIT desc) as hrnk,
      row_number() over (partition by CUST_NO order by TOTAL_DEPOSIT) as lrnk
    from myTable
  ) t
  where hrnk = 1 or lrnk = 1
  group by
    CUST_NO
```

Output:

```
| CUST_NO | DATE_OF_MAX | DATE_OF_MIN |
| ------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1       | 201911      | 201912      |
| 2       | 201910      | 201911      |
| 3       | 201911      | 201912      |
```

Comment: the expected output doesn't match with yours.  But I think from this, I can get what I need simply by getting MIN and MAX TOTAL_DEPOSIT rather than YEAR_MONTH

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my problem in dept, please let us try one more edit. Because I think u thought that I'm trying to get min and max values of YEAR_MONTH but I'm actually trying to take min and max values of TOTAL_DEPOSIT and show corresponding YEAR_MONTH, So 201912 is min because TOTAL_DEPOSIT = 2 is < 926061 and < 82

Comment: @EgeÇıkrıkçı see updated one and how I am using `row_number`. my solution is correct and you can try on your data as well.